# Magic Square 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, fopen

I am tasked with creating a C program that will read a .txt file, convert it into a 2D array, and test whether or not it is a magic square (meaning that all columns, rows, and diagonals add up to `[n(n^2 + 1)] / 2)`, where n is the number of integers in the row, column, or diagonal. The txt file contains 3 4x4 squares, 3 sets of 16 and the last number is zero. So the magic sum is 34. I have gotten the rows to add up, but I can't seem to figure out the columns or the diagonals. Also, I feel that with the way my code is going right now, it will only read the file once, and cannot read the other two 4x4 sets. Here is my code (sorry, it's pretty sloppy right now. I've been wrestling with this for a while, so it got a little messy)

```
int main (){
int array1[4][4], array2[4][4], array3[4][4], number=1, row, col, diag;//I messed with adding new arrays to send to functions, but it doesn't really do anything
FILE *file1;
file1 = fopen ("testdata.txt", "r");
if(file1!=NULL){

printf("     Square         Perfect?\n----------------------------\n");
row=testRows(file1, array1, number);


col=testCols(file1, array3, number);
number++;

}

else
printf("File could not be read.\n");    
return 0;
}


int testRows (FILE *file1, int array1[4][4], int number){
    int i, j=0, r=0, q, tru=9000, array2[4][4], input;
    if (file1!=NULL){
for(q=0; q<4; q++){

    j=0;    
    r=0;


            for (i=0; i<4; i++){

    fscanf(file1, "%d", &array1[i][j]);
    r=r+array1[i][j];//sum of rows

    }
        j++;
    if (r!=34){
        tru=0;
        break;
    }

     if (r==34){
        tru=1;
    }
    }   
}

return tru;
}

int testCols(FILE *file1, int array1[4][4], int num){   //this is the      problematic function
int i, j=0, r=0, q, tru=9000, array2[4][4], input;
if(num==1){//ignore this
file1 = fopen("testdata.txt", "r");//Before I added this, this function would read the next 16 numbers in the file and read their rows, when I need them to read the first 16 and their columns. I feel like this will really hurt when I need the function to read further into the file. Any suggestions? 

}
    if (file1!=NULL){

                for(j=0; j<4; j++){ r=0;
                    for(i=0; i<4; i++){


    fscanf(file1, "%d", &array1[i][j]);

printf("%d ", array1[i][j]);
    r+=array1[i][j];// sum
    printf("   ~%d~  ", r); //this is so I can see what the sum currently  is. For some reason, it will only add up rows and not columns.
    }
printf("\n");
}

//^^^^^ I have moved i's and j's around all over the place, but no matter what, it will print and add the sum of each row.
}
// return tru; variable tru is to return to main whether or not the square is magic; have not gotten that far yet.

}
/*int testDiag(){
}

*/
```

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is `testdata.txt`:

```
1 15 14 4 10 11 8 5 7  6  9  12  16  2  3  13 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 

1  3  4  5  6  7  12  8  9  15  7  9  4  3  12  13  

0
```

UPDATE! 
I redid the entire program, works perfectly now. Take a look:

```
int main(){
int i, j, q, row, col, diag, array1[4][4], magic, magic1, magic2, w, sqn=1;
FILE *file1;
file1= fopen("testdata.txt", "r");
    printf("        Square                  Magic?\n    --------------------------------------\n");
    for(w=0; w<3; w++){

if(file1!=NULL){

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &array1[i][j]);
}}
}
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    row=0;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        row+=array1[i][j];

    }
    if(row==34){
        magic=1;
    }
    if(row!=34){
        magic=0;
        break;
    }
}
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    col=0;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        col+=array1[j][i];
    }
    if(col==34){
        magic1=1;
    }
    if(col!=34){
        magic1=0;
        break;
    }
}
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    diag=0;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        diag+=array1[j][i];
    }
    if(diag==34){
        magic2=1;
    }
    if(diag!=34){
        magic2=0;
        break;
    }
}

printf("      Square  %d              ", sqn);
sqn++;

if(magic==1 && magic1==1 && magic2==1){
printf("   Magic!\n");

}   
else{
    printf("  Not Magic\n");
}

}
fclose(file1);
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Can I have a look on the contents of the file? Post the screen shot of the contents.

Comment: this is testdata.txt                                                                                                         1 15 14 4 10 11 8 5 7  6  9  12  16  2  3  13 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
1  3  4  5  6  7  12  8  9  15  7  9  4  3  12  13  
 
0

Comment: in `testdata.txt` there are 3 complete rows and the 4th row has only 1 element. So how can you construct 4x4 matrix with it? If it's a problem statement for one of the coding contest then post the link to the question.

Comment: I redid the whole thing, put it all in one function. Totally works now. More or less